# Three.js raycast THREE.Object3D

Tags: three.js, collada, raycasting

I want to get the name of an object i clicked at. The model is loaded into the Scene with ColladaLoader.js.
My Problem is, i just get the THREE.Mesh object but i need the THREE.Object3D object, because the Mesh doesn't contain the name.

If i use the following code:

```
scene.traverse (function (object){
    console.log(object);
});
```

I get:

```
THREE.Object3D {uuid: "085928DC-5493-4C57-B142-51D2A95F27B6", name: "Schraube_M4x16_002", type: "Object3D", parent: THREE.Object3D, children: Array[1]…} 
THREE.Mesh {uuid: "1AD3D989-CEB7-4B89-BE88-6D58C1C24AD6", name: "", type: "Mesh", parent: THREE.Object3D, children: Array[0]…}
```

The Object3D has a name the Mesh not. But Raycast only returns meshes How to fix that?

Comment: add a name to your mesh.

Comment: But how to assign the collada names to each mesh. My Collada Model contains many children.

Comment: If you traverse up the tree from your mesh you will hit the Object3D. Otherwise you would have to modify the ColladaLoader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally modifyed the ColladaLoader and added the node's name to the mesh.

```
function createSceneGraph( node, parent ) {
    ...
    // geometries
    ...
    } else {
        if ( geom.isLineStrip === true ) {
            mesh = new THREE.Line ( geom );
        } else {
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh ( geom, material );
        }
        mesh.name = node.name;
    }
    ...
}
```